# extract block of words from specific delimiter

Tags: text-processing

I have a block of words like this, on a single line:

**Id item**: VALUE **nom**: VALUE **type**: VALUE **path**: VALUE **Id item**: VALUE **nom**: VALUE **type**: VALUE **path**: VALUE **Id item**: VALUE **nom**: VALUE **type**: VALUE **path**: VALUE

and i want to get output like this

- **Id item**: VALUE **nom**: VALUE **type**: VALUE **path**: VALUE
- **Id item**: VALUE **nom**: VALUE **type**: VALUE **path**: VALUE
- **Id item**: VALUE **nom**: VALUE **type**: VALUE **path**: VALUE

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/Id item/\nId item/g' file.txt | tail -n +2
```

This will add a new line `\n` to each occurrence of `Id item` then `tail` to cut the first line which is just an empty line.

Comment: thank you, it helps me. There is any caommd that parse lines one by one from input file : i want to use tail command to check last parameter ( path )

Comment: You want to check `path` value in each line or for just last line?

Comment: exactly in each line with specific type value, exmple each line with specific type check for the path

Comment: sed -e 's/Id item/\nId item/g' | awk 'NR!=1{print $NF}'

Comment: `awk` will print only last field `NF` which is value for the `path` and also `NR!=1` is for not printing the first line